# Change function within unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject that needs to call lots of other functions. I was hoping to do something like this[image]

Where I can select the gameobject and script for it to run. I can't figure out how to do this.

I'm calling a function on button click for a gui.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class AvatarSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button general;
    public Button face;
    public Button hair;
    public Button eyebrows;
    public Button clothing;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var root = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;

        general = root.Q<Button>("general");
        face = root.Q<Button>("face");
        hair = root.Q<Button>("hair");
        eyebrows = root.Q<Button>("eyebrows");
        clothing = root.Q<Button>("clothing");

        general.clicked += generalClicked;
        face.clicked += faceClicked;
        hair.clicked += hairClicked;
        eyebrows.clicked += eyebrowsClicked;
        clothing.clicked += clothingClicked;


    }

    void generalClicked()
    {

    }
    void faceClicked()
    {

    }
    void hairClicked()
    {

    }
    void eyebrowsClicked()
    {

    }
    void clothingClicked()
    {

    }


}
```

The 5 bottom functions should do something like the top image. Thanks

Comment: Be careful with dynamic coding.  There's a performance cost which may be unwanted considering you are making a _game._

Answer (score 0):

You can this script which creates buttons in the inspector.

This should be **outside of your AvatarSystem class**.

```
using Unity.Editor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(AvatarSystem))]
public class AvatarSystemGUI : Editor
{
     public override void OnInspectorGUI()
     {
          AvatarSystem t = AvatarSystem(target);
          if (GUILayout.Button("Test"))
          {
               t.ExampleMethod();
          }
     }
 }
```

Let me know of any problems! :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [Unity Event](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html)

You can use UnityEvent<T> to pass a dynamic type in your function.

Then you can use [Unity IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) to capture a click on the object.

[image: Unity Event in Editor]
[image: Unity Event script]

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddListener of UnityEvent;
you can write the code like this;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class AvatarSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button general;
    public Button face;
    public Button hair;
    public Button eyebrows;
    public Button clothing;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var root = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;

        general = root.Q<Button>("general");
        face = root.Q<Button>("face");
        hair = root.Q<Button>("hair");
        eyebrows = root.Q<Button>("eyebrows");
        clothing = root.Q<Button>("clothing");

        general.onClick.AddListener(() => { 
          this.generalClicked();
          this.faceClicked();
          this.hairClicked();
          this.eyebrowsClicked();
          this.clothingClicked();
        }) ; 


    }

    void generalClicked()
    {

    }
    void faceClicked()
    {

    }
    void hairClicked()
    {

    }
    void eyebrowsClicked()
    {

    }
    void clothingClicked()
    {

    }


}
```